# Hibernate session.get() Problem with UUID string ID

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, uuid

I am having a problem with Hibernate.

The primary key of ID in mysql table is UUID style String. e.g.08fe2a75-5d40-4645-896d-aab2a3ac96b8

But I can not use `session.get()` to fetch out the data for some reason.

```
Software software=(Software)session.get(Software.class, id);
```

It seems ok with integer IDs.

Please advise

Comment: What's the error that you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate the logging of the generated SQL to see what is happening exactly. This can be done by setting the following property in your Hibernate configuration:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
```

Or set the following category to debug in the configuration of your logging backend.

```
org.hibernate.SQL
```

Compare the generated query with the expected result (that works in your SQL client).

#### Reference

- Hibernate Core reference guide

  - Section [3.5. "Logging"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging)